# esp8266 1Mbyte (512kb spiffs) missing files

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266, spiffs

I have an issue with spiffs and arduino.

I'm using ESP07 with 1mbyte of spi flash memory. I'm using arduino IDE.

I have 16 files in my file system being sketched with the option "tools -> ESP8266 Sketch data upload". If i selected 256kbytes as SPIFFS size all works fine. All files are there and the system works fine.

But if I use 512 kbytes for SPIFFS only 8 files are there after using the same "tools -> ESP8266 Sketch data upload" option.

I have verified my flash spi memory with the demo included in arduino IDE "CheckFlashConfig", it is 1mbyte.

I need to use the 512 kbytes model because the customer can upload a file that can be too big for 256kb spiffs model.

As curious stuff, I selected 2 mbytes (even when memory is 1mbyte), asigning 1.5mb/512kbspiffs and it worked fine (probably because the last bit address was ignored and it worked over 1mbyte really doing it 512/512).

I have the option to upload all those files manually and it will probably work but it is slower than just burn the memory in production.

Is it a SPIFFS bug? a problem with spiffs in arduino o maybe something that i'm missing?

Thanks.

NOTE: I'm using esp8266 community version 2.5.0 package

Answer (score 0):

Since I am not allowed to comment:

Please upgrade to ESP8266 v2.6.3:
The SPIFFS as standard file system has been replaced by LittleFS (means small changes in code if using the DIR opject), but offers improvements in regard to reliability.
For testing choose Generic ESP8266 with this params 1MB (FS:512KB OTA:~246KB)

If the problem (unlikely) persists or you dont nred OTA check the partition schemes in 
the following boards.txt 
C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\X.X.X\
dependingon theversion can be 2.5.0 or 2.6.3
- you can define your custom scheme if you like